# Converting my VS 2015 Metro App to VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-metro

Good day.

I have made a Metro App (a music player) in VS 2015. This is a project that I need to hand in but also the lecture is working on VS 2013. Now the problem is that I have tried opening it on his PC and it had compatibility issues. Now I dont want to redo my project again due to not enough time. I just want to know is there a way that I can convert or move it to make it Compatible?

Comment: What do you mean by "compatibility issues"? Are you missing some references perhaps in the second computer?

Comment: It just can't open the project and says it has Compatability issues when I open it on VS 2013. doesn't show if anything is missing cuz I cant load

Comment: I Already Answered your Questions based on my Understanding if you have more Details It will help me more in Providing you with the Correct Answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to Open the Project In VS2015 first and from the Project Properties you need to change the Targets

Windows8.1 and .NET Framework 4.5 Anything Higher than that It will not Be Compatible with Older Versions of VS